# My carousel is not working for no specific reason

Tags: html, angularjs, carousel

I have a carousel on angular web app which is supposed to move images on intervals but it is not working as expected, I can not figure out the reason behind --

here's my code

```html
<div id="section1" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="1000">
                  <!-- Indicators -->
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#section1" data-slide-to="0" class="active" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#section1" data-slide-to="1" ></li>
                    <li data-target="#section1" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
                  </ol>
              <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                <div class="item active">
                        <img src="img1.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!-- <h3>Caption Text</h3> -->
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item ">
                        <img src="img2.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!-- <h3>Caption Text</h3> -->
                        </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item ">
                        <img src="img3.jpg" alt="...">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <!--h3>Caption Text</h3-->
                        </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please put this in a jsfiddle or something similar to help make this more easily debuggable?  Also, I'm assuming there's some sort of JS code to help this run that should be included too?  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more info on how to clarify your question for better help.

Comment: Are you using CDN or you download some stylesheets or scripts locally??

Comment: @Ace I was using local files
@w

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones - Thanks, it is mostly due to versions of jquery or bootstrap import files - I am yet to work around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything seems fine, what bootstrap plugin did you used, because the class you have applies requires bootstrap plugin. Please let me know which bootstrap plugin did you use...
try this CDN for bootstrap plugin. It works perfectly with mine

```
 <!--Bootstrap CSS-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!--Bootstrap jquery-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--Bootstrap javascript-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: seems to be the issue, when I run it separately this works fine but when its  on the site I am working its providing no response, may be I need to watch things carefully, thanks